# How to develop support for recursive bundled products?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

How to develop support for recursive bundled products, i.e. it can contain bundled products which in turn can also can contain bundled products, etc...

i want to develop support for maintaining these products in the admin + support for these products to be added to the cart + support for actually creating quotes, orders and invoices that also support it (possibly also things like discounts, refunds, etc) and of course also support for displaying the recursive bundled products properly in both admin and frontend ?

Any idea on how to do it ? Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated ?

Comment: Do you already have a solution for this?

Comment: if i have it then why would i be here :)

Comment: it has been a while, so I was wondering whether you already had found a solution...

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solved the problem?
The links below may help you to (partially) achieve what want.

[Magento: Bundle not adding to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200699/magento-bundle-not-adding-to-cart)

[Having issues displaying bundled products under a bundle product type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136440/having-issues-displaying-bundled-products-under-a-bundle-product-type)

[Magento: Adding a bundled product that is associated to a bundle to a cart returns an error because of getSelectionByIds()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179735/magento-adding-a-bundled-product-that-is-associated-to-a-bundle-to-a-cart-retur)

It doesn't aswer completely what you want, but maybe you can complete the task. If so, please inform how you did it!