# Having issues displaying bundled products under a bundle product type

Tags: magento, bundle

I need assistance completing a custom Magento extension that I am currently developing.  Magento allows the merchant to bundle "simple" products, unfortunately it cannot bundle a "bundled" product.  For example, I have a store that sells computer parts.  I create each individual sellable products, which are considered as "SIMPLE" products.  Next, I want to bundle a keyboard and a mouse together, I can easily do that with Magento by creating a new product type called "BUNDLE PRODUCT" and associate the products to this newly created "BUNDLE PRODUCT".  However if I wanted to associate a bundle product to another bundled product it isn't possible out-of-the-box.

So I created my own extension that would allow me to associate a bundled product to another bundle, which works perfectly in the back-end (product admin tool).  However, I am having an issue having the bundled product to appear on the front-end (product details page). 
**EDIT:**  Typically when you go to view the details of any product (whether it's simple or bundled), you see the details of the whole product (description, name, price, add to cart button, etc.).  On this product detail page there is a box that will appear below the description area to display a list of all the bundled items associated with this product.  This list only appears when you associate a SIMPLE product to the bundle.  I was able to associate bundled products to a "parent" bundle product, however on the product details page -- it does not list them out.  It is just blank.  I can see the title, the description, the add-to-cart button -- however I cannot see the LIST of associated products.

Can anyone help me resolve this or point me to the right direction? I am asking for a solution to have bundled items (product type: bundled product) to appear under the bundled products.

**Here is what you can do to to duplicate the error:**

1) Edit

```
/app/code/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml
```

Add bundle under allowed selection types like so:

```
<allowed_selection_types>
<bundle/>
```

2) Edit

```
/app/code/Mage/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Bundle/Option/Search/Grid
```

and comment out

```
-->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
```

in the _prepareCollection() function. (when you comment out them make sure to semi colon is moved)

3) Edit

```
 /app/code/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php
```

and make the function "isSalable()" to return true for the FIRST "IF STATEMENT".  I did this because for some reason, bundle within a bundle cannot be sold.  It will return "OUT OF STOCK", so I overcame that by having that function return TRUE.

Finally on that same file, modify getSelectionsCollection() by commenting out

```
->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds)
```

(when you comment out them make sure to semi colon is moved)

So now you should be able to associate a BUNDLED product to another BUNDLE product.  When you view the product that contains the bundled product, it will NOT list the bundled items out.  This is where I need help on.  I just need some help where to start looking.

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. This seems like a very broad question that doesn't necessarily have a single direct answer.

Comment: How did you achieve this? Please post some code to demonstrate

Comment: @DanielSloof Thanks for responding.  I updated the question to be a little more specific. Hope this will help.

Comment: @fkim Thanks for responding. I added some code to demonstrate this so you can duplicate my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any progress on this? I've reproduced your steps and achieved the same status. 
It seems to me a problem at /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php@_prepareProduc() - $buyRequest->getBundleOption() might return the correct value.

Comment: No, I haven't made any progress.