# Magento: Bundle not adding to cart

Tags: php, magento, bundle, checkout, shopping-cart

I made a custom Magento extension that would allow bundled product types to be associated with a "parent" bundle product.

For example, if I was selling computer parts and I created a bunch of SIMPLE PRODUCT types (e.g., keyboard, mouse, monitor, etc.) and I created a  bundled product that bundled a Keyboard and a mouse that would work well with what Magento has to offer out-of-the-box. If I created another bundle product type but this time I want to bundle the bundled product that I just made (the one with the keyboard and mouse) I cannot do this.  So what I did was create an extension that allowed me associate the bundled item to a bundle product.

I created a new extension (I called it `Company`) under "local" and under

### `app/code/local/Company/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <bundle>
                <rewrite>
                    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option_search_grid>Company_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option_Search_Grid</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option_search_grid>
                    <adminhtml_catalog_product_composite_fieldset_options_type_checkbox>Company_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Composite_Fieldset_Options_Type_Checkbox</adminhtml_catalog_product_composite_fieldset_options_type_checkbox>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>Company_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Checkbox</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>                
                </rewrite>
            </bundle>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <bundle>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type>Company_Bundle_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
                </rewrite>
            </bundle>
            <bundle_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <option_collection>Company_Bundle_Model_Resource_Option_Collection</option_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </bundle_resource>
        </models>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
                        <label>Bundle Product</label>
                        <model>bundle/product_type</model>
                        <composite>1</composite>
                        <allowed_selection_types>
                            <simple/>
                            <bundle/>
                            <virtual/>
                        </allowed_selection_types>
                        <price_model>bundle/product_price</price_model>
                        <index_data_retreiver>bundle/catalogIndex_data_bundle</index_data_retreiver>
                        <index_priority>40</index_priority>
                        <price_indexer>bundle/indexer_price</price_indexer>
                        <stock_indexer>bundle/indexer_stock</stock_indexer>
                    </bundle>
                </type>
                <options>
                    <bundle>
                        <types>
                            <select translate="label" module="bundle">
                                <label>Drop-down</label>
                            </select>
                            <radio translate="label" module="bundle">
                                <label>Radio Buttons</label>
                            </radio>
                            <checkbox translate="label" module="bundle">
                                <label>Checkbox</label>
                            </checkbox>
                            <multi translate="label" module="bundle">
                                <label>Multiple Select</label>
                            </multi>
                        </types>
                    </bundle>
                </options>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

### `app/code/local/Company/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Bundle/Option/Search/Grid.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option_Search_Grid extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option_Search_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->setStore($this->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('in' => $this->getAllowedSelectionTypes()))
            //->addFilterByRequiredOptions() OVERRIDE!
            ->addStoreFilter();

        if ($products = $this->_getProducts()) {
            $collection->addIdFilter($this->_getProducts(), true);
        }

        if ($this->getFirstShow()) {
            $collection->addIdFilter('-1');
            $this->setEmptyText($this->__('Please enter search conditions to view products.'));
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ID'),
            'sortable'  => true,
            'width'     => '60px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
            'index'     => 'name',
            'column_css_class'=> 'name'
        ));

        $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('set_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $sets,
        ));
        $this->addColumn('type',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'width'     => '80px',
            'index'     => 'sku',
            'column_css_class'=> 'sku'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('price', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'type'      => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
            'rate'      => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
            'index'     => 'price'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('is_selected', array(
            'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'name'      => 'in_selected',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'values'    => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('qty', array(
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty to Add'),
            'name'      => 'qty',
            'inline_css'=> 'qty',
            'align'     => 'right',
            'type'      => 'input',
            'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
            'index'     => 'qty',
            'width'     => '130px',
        ));

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

### `app/code/local/Company/Bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Composite/Fieldset/Options/Type/Checkbox.php`

```
<?php


class Company_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Composite_Fieldset_Options_Type_Checkbox
    extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Composite_Fieldset_Options_Type_Checkbox
{
    /**
     * Set template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('Company/bundle/list.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $elementId
     * @param  string $containerId
     * @return string
     */
    public function setValidationContainer($elementId, $containerId)
    {
        return '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(\'' . $elementId . '\').advaiceContainer = \'' . $containerId . '\';
            </script>';
    }
}
```

### `app/code/local/Company/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option/Checkbox.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Checkbox
    extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Checkbox
{
    /**
     * Set template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/list.phtml');
    }
}
```

### `app/code/local/Company/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php`

```
    <?php
class Company_Bundle_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
{
    /**
     * Checking if we can sale this bundle
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSalable($product = null)
    {
        $salable = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::isSalable($product);
        if (!is_null($salable)) {
            return true; /* OVERRIDE! */
        }

        $optionCollection = $this->getOptionsCollection($product);

        if (!count($optionCollection->getItems())) {
            return false;
        }

        $requiredOptionIds = array();

        foreach ($optionCollection->getItems() as $option) {
            if ($option->getRequired()) {
                $requiredOptionIds[$option->getId()] = 0;
            }
        }

        $selectionCollection = $this->getSelectionsCollection($optionCollection->getAllIds(), $product);

        if (!count($selectionCollection->getItems())) {
            return false;
        }
        $salableSelectionCount = 0;
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
            if ($selection->isSalable()) {
                $requiredOptionIds[$selection->getOptionId()] = 1;
                $salableSelectionCount++;
            }

        }

        return (array_sum($requiredOptionIds) == count($requiredOptionIds) && $salableSelectionCount);
    }

    /**
     * Retrive bundle selections collection based on used options
     *
     * @param array $optionIds
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Selection_Collection
     */
    public function getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $product = null)
    {
        $keyOptionIds = (is_array($optionIds) ? implode('_', $optionIds) : '');
        $key = $this->_keySelectionsCollection . $keyOptionIds;
        if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($key)) {
            $storeId = $this->getProduct($product)->getStoreId();
            $selectionsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id') //used for calculation item taxes in Bundle with Dynamic Price
                ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
                ->setFlag('product_children', true)
                ->setPositionOrder()
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
                ->setStoreId($storeId);
                //->addFilterByRequiredOptions() OVERRIDE!
                //->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds) OVERRIDE!
            if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isPriceGlobal() && $storeId) {
                $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
                $selectionsCollection->joinPrices($websiteId);
            }

            $this->getProduct($product)->setData($key, $selectionsCollection);
        }
        return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($key);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare product and its configuration to be added to some products list.
     * Perform standard preparation process and then prepare of bundle selections options.
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $buyRequest
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param string $processMode
     * @return array|string
     */
    protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
    {
        $result = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);

        if (is_string($result)) {
            return $result;
        }

        $selections = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct($product);
        $isStrictProcessMode = $this->_isStrictProcessMode($processMode);

        $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
        $_appendAllSelections = (bool)$product->getSkipCheckRequiredOption() || $skipSaleableCheck;

        $options = $buyRequest->getBundleOption();

        if (is_array($options)) {
            $options = array_filter($options, 'intval');
            $qtys = $buyRequest->getBundleOptionQty();
            foreach ($options as $_optionId => $_selections) {
                if (empty($_selections)) {
                    unset($options[$_optionId]);
                }
            }
            $optionIds = array_keys($options);

            if (empty($optionIds) && $isStrictProcessMode) {
                return Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Please select options for product.');
            }

            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);
            $optionsCollection = $this->getOptionsCollection($product);
            $selectionIds = array();

            foreach ($options as $optionId => $selectionId) {
                if (!is_array($selectionId)) {
                    if ($selectionId != '') {
                        $selectionIds[] = (int)$selectionId;
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($selectionId as $id) {
                        if ($id != '') {
                            $selectionIds[] = (int)$id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If product has not been configured yet then $selections array should be empty
            if (!empty($selectionIds)) {
                $selections = $this->getSelectionsByIds($selectionIds, $product);

                // Check if added selections are still on sale
                foreach ($selections->getItems() as $key => $selection) {
                    if (!$selection->isSalable() && !$skipSaleableCheck) {
                        $_option = $optionsCollection->getItemById($selection->getOptionId());
                        if (is_array($options[$_option->getId()]) && count($options[$_option->getId()]) > 1) {
                            $moreSelections = true;
                        } else {
                            $moreSelections = false;
                        }
                        if ($_option->getRequired()
                            && (!$_option->isMultiSelection() || ($_option->isMultiSelection() && !$moreSelections))
                        ) {
                            return Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Selected required options are not available.');
                        }
                    }
                }

                $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selections, false, $_appendAllSelections);

                $selections = $selections->getItems();
            } else {
                $selections = array();
            }           
        } else {
            $product->setOptionsValidationFail(true);
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

            $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($product);

            $optionIds = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product);
            $selectionIds = array();

            $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getSelectionsCollection(
                    $optionIds,
                    $product
                );

            $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false, $_appendAllSelections);

            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option->getRequired() && count($option->getSelections()) == 1) {
                    $selections = array_merge($selections, $option->getSelections());
                } else {
                    $selections = array();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count($selections) > 0 || !$isStrictProcessMode) {
            $uniqueKey = array($product->getId());
            $selectionIds = array();

            // Shuffle selection array by option position
            usort($selections, array($this, 'shakeSelections'));

            foreach ($selections as $selection) {
                if ($selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty() && isset($qtys[$selection->getOptionId()])) {
                    $qty = (float)$qtys[$selection->getOptionId()] > 0 ? $qtys[$selection->getOptionId()] : 1;
                } else {
                    $qty = (float)$selection->getSelectionQty() ? $selection->getSelectionQty() : 1;
                }
                $qty = (float)$qty;

                $product->addCustomOption('selection_qty_' . $selection->getSelectionId(), $qty, $selection);
                $selection->addCustomOption('selection_id', $selection->getSelectionId());

                $beforeQty = 0;
                $customOption = $product->getCustomOption('product_qty_' . $selection->getId());
                if ($customOption) {
                    $beforeQty = (float)$customOption->getValue();
                }
                $product->addCustomOption('product_qty_' . $selection->getId(), $qty + $beforeQty, $selection);

                /*
                 * Create extra attributes that will be converted to product options in order item
                 * for selection (not for all bundle)
                 */
                $price = $product->getPriceModel()->getSelectionFinalTotalPrice($product, $selection, 0, $qty);
                $attributes = array(
                    'price'         => Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($price),
                    'qty'           => $qty,
                    'option_label'  => $selection->getOption()->getTitle(),
                    'option_id'     => $selection->getOption()->getId()
                );

                $_result = $selection->getTypeInstance(true)->prepareForCart($buyRequest, $selection);
                if (is_string($_result) && !is_array($_result)) {
                    return $_result;
                }

                if (!isset($_result[0])) {
                    return Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add item to the shopping cart.');
                }

                $result[] = $_result[0]->setParentProductId($product->getId())
                    ->addCustomOption('bundle_option_ids', serialize(array_map('intval', $optionIds)))
                    ->addCustomOption('bundle_selection_attributes', serialize($attributes));

                if ($isStrictProcessMode) {
                    $_result[0]->setCartQty($qty);
                }

                $selectionIds[] = $_result[0]->getSelectionId();
                $uniqueKey[] = $_result[0]->getSelectionId();
                $uniqueKey[] = $qty;
            }

            // "unique" key for bundle selection and add it to selections and bundle for selections
            $uniqueKey = implode('_', $uniqueKey);
            foreach ($result as $item) {
                $item->addCustomOption('bundle_identity', $uniqueKey);
            }
            $product->addCustomOption('bundle_option_ids', serialize(array_map('intval', $optionIds)));
            $product->addCustomOption('bundle_selection_ids', serialize($selectionIds));

            return $result;
        }

        return $this->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
    }



    /**
     * Retrieve message for specify option(s)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSpecifyOptionMessage()
    {
        return Mage::helper('bundle')->__('Please specify product option(s).');
    }

}
```

### `app/code/local/Company/Bundle/Model/Resource/Option/Collection.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Bundle_Model_Resource_Option_Collection extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Option_Collection
{
    /**
     * Append selection to options
     * stripBefore - indicates to reload
     * appendAll - indicates do we need to filter by saleable and required custom options
     *
     * @param Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Selection_Collection $selectionsCollection
     * @param bool $stripBefore
     * @param bool $appendAll
     * @return array
     */
    public function appendSelections($selectionsCollection, $stripBefore = false, $appendAll = true)
    {
        if ($stripBefore) {
            $this->_stripSelections();
        }

        if (!$this->_selectionsAppended) {
            foreach ($selectionsCollection->getItems() as $key => $_selection) {
                if ($_option = $this->getItemById($_selection->getOptionId())) {
                    $_selection->setOption($_option);
                    $_option->addSelection($_selection);
                }
            }
            $this->_selectionsAppended = true;
        }

        return $this->getItems();
    }
}
```

This should be everything.  There is a reference to LIST.phtml but you can change that to checkbox if you want.  However, If you add a bundle within a bundle -- it works till I get to add it to my cart. Any help on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated?

**UPDATE:**
So I was able to tracked down why I can’t add a ‘parent’ bundle product to my shopping cart,

```
protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
```

Which is located under Type.php and I found that the issue might be somewhat related to

```
public function getSelectionsByIds($selectionIds, $product = null)
```

because it returns no “selections” (not a null but no selections, compared to a bundle product with SIMPLE product types) AND because it gives a null for `getItems()`.  If I remove

```
->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
```

from the function `getSelectionsByIds`, I can get something back from `getItems()` but it will crash on

```
$_result = $selection->getTypeInstance(true)->prepareForCart($buyRequest, $selection);
```

.
Please help!  I just need someway for this “parent” bundle be added to my shopping cart much like a regular bundled product would.  Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Did you had any progress on this? Thanks!

Comment: I've started a bounty for this question. I'm using Magento 1.7 and after reproducing Simon's steps I achieve the same status. When try to adding a product to the cart (via Admin Panel) it crashes in the background. Hoping someone can help us.

Comment: @matheusjardimb Thanks for starting the bounty, unfortunately I haven't made any progress on this.  I kind of abandoned this because I wasn't able to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box suggestion without needing such a complex solution. We sell bundle kits in magento but I set them up as Simple Products instead and simply use the related products to assign any type of products (in your case other bundle kits or any other type of product). We simply add a new block to the product page which shows the related products as we require and give it the title of kit contents instead. When the user adds the item to the cart it is just the simple product. You could also add a block to the cart page which shows the related items under the item on the cart listing page. Historically we had problems with magento and bundle kits and sometimes people could not checkout without removing it and re-adding it, and this solution solved that completely and would give you the functionality required. We don't use the admin though to administer products or orders (all done through api and back office) but principle could be taken into the admin for orders etc.